# Como hago para cambiar los datos de posicion de un vector?

Tags: java, array, poo, condiciones, clase

Buenos dias tengo este problema y me piden que cambia los datos de posicion de un vector, el vector tiene datos de isbn, titulo, precio, cantidadDisponible, cantidadVendida. pero yo no se como hago para cambiarle su posicion ayuda please

, [image: Descripcion requerimiento]

```
aqui estan partes del programa

//Atributos de la clase
private Scanner sc;
private Libro[] libros = new Libro[3];


 public String consultarTodosLosLibros() {
    String resultado = "";
    resultado += "\nLibros:";
    for (int i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {
        resultado += "\n" + (i + 1) + ". ";
        if (libros[i] == null) {
            resultado += "Espacio disponible.";
        } else {
            resultado += libros[i];
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}


   public void cambiarLibroPosicion() {
    System.out.println(consultarTodosLosLibros());
    System.out.println("Ingrese los datos separados por & (libro a cambiar, nuevo espacio):");
    String texto = sc.nextLine();
     String [] dato = texto.split("&");
     int posicionLibro = Integer.parseInt(dato[0]) -1 ;
     int espacioCambio = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);

    //falta aqui los condiciones y requerimientos ayuda
     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diría que te enfrentas un reto clásico en la programación. Si recibes el libro que vas a mover y asumes que siempre habrá un libro en ese espacio, y también te dan la posición a la que debes de mover ese libro, simplemente tendrías que intercambiar esas dos posiciones en el array. El lugar de destino lo puedes almacenar en una variable temporal para cubrir el supuesto en el que no sea nulo.

```
Libro libroEnEspacioDeCambio = libros[espacioDeCambio];

libros[espacioDeCambio] = libros[posicionLibro];
libros[posicionLibro] = libroEnEspacioDeCambio;
```

Comment: Gracias crack ya me funciona,